# KafkaTool: Can't connet to Kafka cluster

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to connect to the Kafka using a KafkaTool. I got an error:
Error connecting to the cluster. failed create new KafkaAdminClient

Kafka and Zookeeper is hosting in the Docker. I run next commands

```
   docker network create kafka
   docker run --network=kafka -d --name zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
   docker run --network=kafka -d -p 9092:9092 --name kafka -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092 -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
```

Settings for KafkaTool
[image]

[image]

Why does KafkaTool not connect to the Kafka that is hosting in the Docker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming this GUI is not coming from a Docker container. Therefore, your host machine doesn't know what `zookeeper` or `kafka` are, only the Docker network does.

In the GUI, you will want to use `localhost` for both, then in your Kafka run command, leave all the other variables alone but change `-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`

Zookeeper run command is fine, but add `-p 2181:2181` to expose the port out to the host so that the GUI can connect

Comment: if I add KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:2181 kafka can't connect to zookeeper and showed error "Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181: Connection refused.". How can I resolve it?

Comment: Because zookeeper isn't running on localhost, it is running on a different container... WIthin docker containers, then localhost refers to the container itself, not your host machine. What you have in the question is correct - why did you change it?

Comment: I changed my question to unanswered because in your answer  you mentioned “In the GUI, you will want to use localhost for both”. I set KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:2181 and -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092. But still I can’t connect to the Kafka using Kafka tool. Can you provide me correct example please ?

Comment: Yes, in the GUI, only... Your original docker run commands were perfectly fine except for the only variable and port mapping I mentioned

Comment: Sorry, incorrect previous comment. I changed docker commands as you mentioned add -p 2181:2181 and change -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 : docker run --network=kafka -d --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest docker run --network=kafka -d -p 9092:9092 --name kafka -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest. But still I can’t connect in the GUI. Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200279/discussion-between-mastermedia-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Docker and the GUI are on the same machine? If so, localhost:9092 and localhost:2181 are what values go into the GUI (I've yet to test the GUI, but Kafka CLI commands work fine with that configuration)